# segmentation fault in height balance tree code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, avl-tree

When i try to do like this:

```
int main(){

    node * root;

    insert(&root, 10);
    insert(&root, 20);
    insert(&root, 30);
    insert(&root, 40);
    insert(&root, 50);
    insert(&root,60);

    preorder(root);

return 0;
}
```

my code runs fine and gives output.

But when i do this:

```
int main(){

    node * root;

    insert(&root, 10);
    insert(&root, 20);
    insert(&root, 30);
    insert(&root, 40);
    insert(&root, 50);
    insert(&root,60);

    preorder(root);

    node * t;

    insert(&t,9);
    insert(&t,15);
    insert(&t,18);
    insert(&t,33);
    insert(&t,55);
    insert(&t,44);
    insert(&t,61);

return 0;
}
```

It gives a segmentation fault...

Also if i comment:

```
preorder(root);
```

the code just works fine..

If i do the preorder of node t at last it works fine...
Don't know how i am getting this segmentation error when i try to print the preorder of root before t?

**Code segment for insert:**

```
void insert(node ** root, int d){
    node * t= *root;

    *root=_insert(t,d);
}

node * _insert(node * t, int d){
    if(t==NULL)
        return newNode(d);
    else{

        if(d < t->data)
            t->left=_insert(t->left,d);

        if(d > t->data)
            t->right=_insert(t->right,d);

        t->height= max(ht(t->left),ht(t->right))+1;

        int bal= ht(t->left)-ht(t->right);

        if(bal > 1 && d < t->data)
            return rightRotate(t);

        if(bal < -1 && d > t->data)
            return leftRotate(t);

        if(bal < -1  && d > t->data){
            t->right=rightRotate(t->right);
            return leftRotate(t);
        }   

        if(bal >1 && d < t->data){
            t->left=leftRotate(t->left);
            return rightRotate(t);
        }

        return t;
    }
}
```

**Code segment of preorder:**

```
void preorder(node * t){
    if(t==NULL)
        return;

    else {
        cout<<t->data<<" ";
        preorder(t->left);
        preorder(t->right);
    }
}
```

**Helper functions used in code and node structure:**

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node * left;
    node * right;
    int height;
};


node * newNode(int d){
    node * t;
    t= new node;
    t->data = d;
    t->left=NULL;
    t->right=NULL;
    t->height=1;
    return t;
}


int ht(node * t){
    if(t==NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return t->height;
}

node * leftRotate(node * t){
    node * y = t->right;
    t->right= y->left;
    y->left=t;

    return y;
}


node * rightRotate(node * t){
    node * y = t->left;
    t->left= y->right;
    y->right=t;

    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, because local variables are not initialized, their values are *indeterminate*.

You need to initialize the variables before you try to use them, e.g.

```
node* root = nullptr;  // or `0` or `NULL`
```

Comment: This precisely solved the problem.Kudos.